# Laravel HTTP Client Retrieve REST API Access Token

Tags: authentication, access-token, guzzle, laravel-7

Trying to retrieve an access token from MS Azure

something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Response;

class HttpController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantId]/oauth2/token";

        $response = HTTP::post($url,
        [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_Id' => 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'client_secret' => '***************************',
            'resource' => 'https://management.azure.com',
        ]);

         dd($response);
    }
}
```

get the following error:

> "error": "invalid_request",
> "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = HTTP::asForm()->post($url,
        [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_Id' => 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'client_secret' => '***************************',
            'resource' => 'https://management.azure.com',
            ]
        );
```